# Clojure methods ending in *

Tags: clojure

What do methods ending in `*` tend to have in common? I've seen a few, but have no idea if this is an established naming convention.

Answer (score 2):

In general I've seen this used to distinguish functions that do the same thing but with different signatures, especially in situations where overloads would create conflicting semantics.  For example, `list*` could not be expressed as an overload of `list` because they are using variable arity in different ways.

In many cases (but not all), the `*` form is called by the non-`*` version.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from what other answers have mentioned, This convention is used where the non-* version are macros and these macros emit code that calls the * functions. Even in `clojure.core`, `let` and `fn` are macros whose resulting code calls `let*` and `fn*` functions respectively. Other example would be [sqlkorma](https://github.com/korma/Korma/blob/master/src/korma/core.clj), where non-* (`where`,`delete`,`update` etc) are macros and * ones (`where*`, `delete*` etc) are functions.

The reason for using this pattern is that in some cases it is not feasible to use the macro version of the API (apart from using eval, as you don't have the information at compile time), in such cases you can uses the * based functions.

Comment: `let*` and `fn*` are not functions. They're special forms, that is, they are directly understood and handled by the compiler. `let` and `fn` are convenience macros adding destructuring support and, in the case of `fn`, pre/postconditions support. Another special form / macro pair is `letfn*` / `letfn`; here the purpose of the macro is to provide a surface syntax more convenient than that directly supported by the special form.